How to not Repeat Myself: declare the interface and also the state
So, in Typescript and React, is it normal to repeat the code in the interface and in the state (in the component). For example, in types/profileTypes.ts:
export interface Profile {
  id: number;
  user: User;  // User interface
  interests: string;
  profile_description: string;
  timezone: string;
  is_teacher: boolean;
}

then in ProfileData.tsx:
const initializeProfile = (): Profile => {
  return {
    id: 0, 
    user: {
      id: 0,
      username: '',
      email: ''
    },
    interests: '',
    profile_description: '',
    timezone: '',
    is_teacher: false,
  };
};

const ProfileData = () => {
  const [profile, setProfile] = useState<Profile>(initializeProfile());

is this normal? if not, which is the correct approach? Everytime I change something in the model I'll need to change it in several places in the frontend... doesn't seem right.

This looks normal enough to me.

I don't see a repetition here. One code defines an interface with types, the other creates an object with property values.

If you wanted to avoid repeating the property names at all cost, you could write const emptyProfile = { id: 0, user: { … } as User, … }; type Profile = typeof emptyProfile;. However using property names in multiple places is perfectly normal.

"Everytime I change something in the model I'll need to change it in several places in the frontend..." - that's the design goal of TypeScript in the first place! If you didn't have the type declaration, you would have forgotten to change the code in those places in the frontend, and your app would have broken down?

So you want to change the type, and have not have to change the values you are assigning to those types? How would the type know that you want to initialize string to ''? The whole point of a type is to make it safe and predictable wherever you use that type. You have to come up with the value that makes sense in that part of the code that matches that new type property, and the type itself couldn't possibly know what that should be. So yeah, completely normal, even desired, and I can't imagine how else it would work.

If you don't want to declare the type and only rely on the function's return data shape itself, try type Profile = ReturnType<typeof initializeProfile>; - see https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypetype

While it's fairly normal to go about it in that way, there are other ways to get the same type safety without having to manually create the type itself. You can use the ReturnType utility to generate your type:


const initializeProfile = () => {
  return {
    id: 0, 
    user: {
      id: 0,
      username: '',
      email: ''
    },
    interests: '',
    profile_description: '',
    timezone: '',
    is_teacher: false,
  };
};

type Profile = ReturnType<typeof initializeProfile>;

const ProfileData = () => {
  const [profile, setProfile] = useState<Profile>(initializeProfile());

  return (
    <div>
      {profile.id} // TS sees 'number' (or the value 0)
      {profile.notFound} // <-- TS error
    </div>
  );
}



Now if you change properties from the return value of initializeProfile, it will automatically be reflected in the referenced Profile type.
